# how to not attach stdout of Python pipes instance to a file?

Tags: python, pipe

In the Python manual on `pipes` the example is given to use `f = t.open('pipefile', 'w')` so the `stdout` from the pipe will go to the file `pipefile`.  I can use it like this:

```
import pipes
import sys
t = pipes.Template()
t.append('tr a-z A-Z', '--')
f = t.open('pipefile', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print('hello world')
```

and after I execute this script, I see "HELLO WORLD" in the file `pipefile`.

But I don't want to direct the `stdout` of the pipe to a file.  I want to leave it alone.  So that, when I execute this script, it prints `HELLO WORLD`.

I need to change the two lines somehow:

```
f = t.open('pipefile', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
```

How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to print to both the file and stdout?

Comment: No, only stdout.  I just looked at the module `pipes` and saw that it is used to construct pipes, so I thought, this is the place.  Looks like it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  Looks like the module `pipes`, which it would seem, should have such functionality relating to pipes, does not have that feature - it can only be used to redirect pipes to files, but not to leave them at `stdout`.

To do what I want, I don't need the module `pipes`, instead, I need the module `os`, like this

```
import os, sys
sys.stdout = os.popen('tr a-z A-Z','w',1)
print('hello world')
```